# nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C11] Hit maximum timestamp count, will start dropping events

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

No idea what this is, I've tried searching this on google and on stack overflow and there has been no definitive answer to my question.

"nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C11] Hit maximum timestamp count, will start dropping events"

prints in console and then closes some of my views, leading to a buggy user experience.

Anyone got any info on where this is coming from?

Comment: Is this pure SwfitUI or UIKit & SwiftUI? To me it screams that your logging is reaching it's maximum limit, likely due to some infinite loop which is especially easy to do when manipulating state on SwiftUI views. That would both explain the logs, and the views closing. You might look for any `Purple` labels that are present on some of the views that are closing and double check for infinite recursion.

Comment: You'll have to show some code of your view where this log occurs, this isn't very helpful atm.